# BizTalk 2010 server returning error

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

All BizTalk 2010 applications on one server stopped working and creating same message:

Routing Failure Report for "Routing Failure Report for "[port-name-here]"

```
This service instance exists to help debug routing failures for instance "{B79F1529-4796-4CE3-A749-4FA8890A7601}". The context of the message associated with this instance contains all the promoted properties at the time of the routing failure.
```

They are working well on other servers.

What could cause this problem and what would be best way to fix it ?

UPDATE:There was some king of database cleaning script was executed on BizTalk database. Is there way to validate if there is issue into BizTalk database ?

One possible solution is to reinstall BizTalk application , but I want to make learning experience from it and figure out how to troubleshoot such problems.

Comment: There should be more in the Event Log.

Comment: Are all send ports enlisted?

Comment: yes, they all enlisted.

Comment: Filter for all Subscriptions in Group overview in BizTalk Admin Console and confirm if you can check the Send port having a subscription

Answer (score 1):

It seems like no Subscribers are being found for the message.
Please make sure that the subscribing Send port or the Orchestration are enabled and their corresponding host instances are in enabled mode as well.
Also, if the Send ports are using any context property filters to subscribe to the message, make sure that the filter is correct and the context property values for the received message is correct.

Comment: all subscribers intact into administration console. application was running before.